# How to use errors to improve a regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, error

I want to use a model to predict the errors of my model in order to improve it but I am confused in how to do that. I am seeking some help to understand how to procede.

I have 100 data points and I used a SARIMA model to the estimate the final 5. So, I used 95 data points as my test data and 5 as my training. After the estimative, I calculated the residuals.

Now I am interested to use another model to estimate the residuals and to sum this estimative to my original estimative in order to improve it. My final estimative would be: estimative = residual_estimate + original_estimate

I was think about using 80 data points to predict the next 20. After that, to calculate the residuals of the following 15 data points and use a model to predict the following 5 error data points. I would add this final estimative of the errors to my original estimative.

Is this right? Is that way that people do?

Comment: This is a bit related to [tag:boosting].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was noted in the comment this is kinda boosting although you are fitting your 'error' model on the test set whereas typically the model is just fit on your training set.  And boosting is highly iterative while your procedure sounds more like a 2 step procedure. I can see why you would be motivated to do this in the time-series context as the training set would fit too well but I am not aware of this exact implementation being done.

I would imagine boosting on the fitted results would regularize your ARIMA parameters.  Whereas boosting using the predictions would give you, on average, worst performance unless you have a ton of data and specifically tons of seasonal periods to do this with and you add other features such as the period to the error model. Another major issue comes down to time series in general, if you for some reason over-forecast because we can't know the future then your error model would think it needs to under-forecast. However your sarimax model would just naturally adapt to the new level the next time you forecast. So your error model would always be living in the 'past'.

In general, boosting in the time series context I have mainly seen done for changepoint analysis such as wild binary segmentation.